# cannot use azure data factory as it is advertised

Tags: azure-data-factory

part of what I posted at https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Dataflows/getting-started-with-data-factory/m-p/3356926#M465 relates to the azure data factory (adf) obstacle I am encountering.  The experts there recommended I come here.

To repeat what I wrote there about adf, the first image below shows the data factory instance I started. To the best of my knowledge, I am supposed to see a power query authoring/mashup visual when I choose Power Query and New and perhaps the greyed authoring pencil.  Much like what shows at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-power-query-activity in item 4 under "Create a Power Query activity with UI" and in my second image. But it doesn't.  Things that might be relevant are 1) i have a trial premium license, 2) i have a
"teams exploratory license" as shown in image 3, 3) at the moment my tenant work acct has global admin privileges in my azure/ms 365 personal subscription (as suggested by ms for a similar power automate issue) and a "data factory contributor role" which i assigned when i ran out of ideas.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> **First Add a Source dataset for your Power Query mash-up. You can either choose an existing dataset or create a new one.**

- **You can  create dataset as below:**
  **Datasets >> Three dots >> new dataset**
  [image]
- When using **Power Query** first you need select the appropriate dataset with correct mapping from dropdown on which you want to use the Power Query.
  [image]
- Then select the dataset and you will see the mashup visual.
  [image]

Reference: [Power Query in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/wrangling-tutorial)

Comment: i opened a case 2308080040010434 with MS.    My tech says what i ask (creating a pq/ds from scratch) is impossible in adf.  That I would have to choose blob data or synapse etc or one of the 3 (of 5) other connector types  where a "notebook" (not sure what its called) script already exists to use python in/as an adf data source.  Essentially I would have to pay for one of those 5 technologies to "contain" a connector that is otherwise free.  Asked her for one of her supervisors just so I can confirm all this on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand from my meeting (re ticket 2308080040010434) with MS today what my issue is with ADF.  The first tech had it right weeks ago but i didn't understand her.  And I think Pratik answered it correctly but I wasn't understanding.  The simplest way to put it is that ADF expects as a source something already "in tabular" form or "appearing to be in tabular" form via abstracted scripts in azure notebooks etc. And while in power bi (PBI) a dataset contains 1 or more power queries (PQ's) , its almost the opposite in ADF, i.e. a PQ appears to be able to use an ADF dataset.  An ADF dataset looks like it can use as a connector an item from a long list of technologies including on prem SQL, Excel and Dynamics.  But if you don't use (or maybe in addition to using) a dataset in a new PQ, then you can connect that PQ to 1 of 5 azure (synapse ETC) technologies I think to create a different kind of source in ADF. In my case, the hope of using ADF to connect to a free data source like Yahoo's ticker data just isn't going to happen without some kind of middle tier storage technology.  I am hopeful though when we figure out how I can use fabric data factory (it isn't working for me right now) that it will be more flexible and similar to the PBI PQ experience where even a python based read against Yahoo data is doable without a middle layer of storage technology.